# How to correctly set pv size in shell script

Tags: shell, pipe, size

I am writing backup script and want to see correct progress of tar.
Main part of script:

```
backup_file="root-backup-$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S).tar"
sudo -v
sudo mount /dev/vg/root /mnt
time sudo sh -c "cd /mnt; tar --xattrs -cf - . | pv -s $(du -sb | grep -o '[0-9]*') > /backup/${backup_file}"
```

But pv show fast filling progress bar and then number increasing up to 100000%.

**Upd1.** Misprints fixed in script. Actually it works, but progress bar is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: `$(du -sb | grep -o '[0-9]*')` is not calling under new subshell - it is calling as command substitution.

So, before run `sudo sh -c` bash calls `$(du -sb | grep -o '[0-9]*')` in some current directory (that was smaller in my case) and substitute result into string.

As a result `pv -s` has incorrect size and show incorrect progress.

I've decided to **prevent substitution** surrounding sign `$` with single quotes:

`time sudo sh -c "cd /mnt; tar --xattrs -cf - . | pv -s "'$'"(du -sb | grep -o '[0-9]*') > /backup/${backup_file}"`